# Unable to @mention Partner user on chatter feed by Salesforce Internal User

Tags: chatter, partner-portal, community

I have a usecase wherein a Partner user creates a Case which gets assigned to internal Salesforce user. The agent resolves the case and wanted to collaborate with the partner user with @mention tags but unfortunately, its not coming up. Is this a bug or work as designed .
However, the inverse works, from a partner community chatter feed I am able to @mention salesforce internal user.

Any inputs are welcome

Thanks
JJ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two things must happen in order to @mention a community user on a record feed. The record must be viewed and the Chatter post initiated by the internal user in the communities context. In other words, you must be viewing the record with the Community base URL( e.g. https://mycommunity.force.com/recordid ). Second, the visibility of the Chatter post from the internal user must be set to Everyone. The default is internal users.

EDIT: To add, this is not a bug, this is by design. Communities users are not part of your internal Salesforce CRM. Although records can span communities and your "internal" community, Chatter on those records is contextual to the place you are posting it.

Comment: yes, this helps to expose comments for all but still not able to mention the partner user when logged in via Internal user. however the partner user can mention the internal user, even in a scenario where both the users have access to same Case Record.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right, you must be viewing the record in the context of the community in order to @mention the community user. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Most of the scenarios, the agents who works on cases uses Service Cloud Console. Switching back to community to collaborate with the partner user doesn't looks good from usability perspective. Do you agree ?

Comment: I don't disagree with you, I'm just explaining how it works and answering your question. I can see how this would make life harder for service agents. One way to get around this is to create a formula field that exposes a link to the record in the community context.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick replies on this question. Thanks for your explanation :)..for now, i think back-n f0rth is the only way for the agents to work!! Damn, they are so stressed in their job already.. lol

Comment: If you think I've answered your question, please vote on my answer and/or mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Just an FYI, even if I do a workaround of swtiching from console to community, it redirects to login page first :(

Answer (score 3):

When I am posting **to a record**, as an Internal User I **am** able to @mention a Partner User from the Internal side with no problem. I have to set the "All with Access" option in the lower left corner of the post form field for the Partner to see the post, however.

The Partner User then gets the record post notification and can answer. I see the answer fine and we can continue to exchange comments even without @mentions and we can both see them from our respective side of the "fence" (Partner in the Community context and me in the Internal context).

This does **not** work if you make a general chatter post. I cannot @mention the Partner User from there, I have to go to the Community Context.

Hope this helps