# System Admin @mention Community user not working

Tags: community, chatter

Logged in user is a system admin. When I try to post on chatter tab using @communityUser I am not getting user suggestion. Cant we access Community user @mention?

I tried to find an answer here - ([Unable to @mention Partner user on chatter feed by Salesforce Internal User](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17605/unable-to-mention-partner-user-on-chatter-feed-by-salesforce-internal-user))

- First of all, The answer to above question is related to record
  post/feed. But i am not posting feed on any record to make it view
  with the Community base URL. **I am trying to post from Chatter tab**.
- Secondly, the answer suggests the visibility of the Chatter post from
  the internal user must be set to Everyone. The default is internal
  users. - **I didn't find any way mentioned in the answer to achieve

  this**(how to set this visibility?)

Please suggest if I am missing some customization setting to do

Comment: @VamsiKrishna i read that but i am having hard time understanding it. can you elaborate? The answer says "Second, the visibility of the Chatter post from the internal user must be set to Everyone. " How to achieve this?

Comment: The visibility setting only applies to posts on records. If you're posting to a Chatter group or user profile (including your own profile, which I think is what you're doing), there is no visibility setting to toggle.

Answer (score 3):

Administrators can mention people specific to current community. If that post is in internal community, he can't mention external community users.

```
Can mention people specific to the current community. User can’t mention an external user on an internal post.
```

Please refer in the documention **Who Can See What in Communities** [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=networks_visibility.htm&language=en_US)